# java getInputArguments() returns awkward results if system property value contains spaces

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, system-properties

Consider a main method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("property='" +  System.getProperty("property") + "'");
    List<String> inputArgs = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
    System.out.println("jvm input args size: " + inputArgs.size());
    System.out.println("jvm input args: " + inputArgs);
}
```

Results from running the program:

```
>java -Dproperty=hey!
property='hey!'
jvm input args size: 1
jvm input args: [-Dproperty=hey!]

>java -Dproperty="one two three"
property='one two three'
jvm input args size: 3 //but there's only one input property!
jvm input args: [-Dproperty=one, two, three] //!!!
```

At least that's the behavior on Oracle/Sun's jvm 6 on mac) & on win (haven't tested elsewhere).

Does anyone know a way of getting input args that is reliable when system properties contain spaces?

Comment: Print out `args.length` too - it's `getInputArguments()` that is splitting up the quoted argument (i.e. it's not the JVMs fault!)

Comment: Whoever's fault it is - the behavior is clearly wrong.  I suggest filing a bug with Oracle.

Comment: If what you want is system properties, then access `System.getProperties()`.  `-Dxxx=yyy` defines a system property.  The parsing of the command line properties depends on your shell as well as the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a known issue which may have been fixed in JDK7: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=f84d44729bd8affffffffeb9b87963e2d752?bug_id=6459832